# When to use javascript to adjust content height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need all of the content to load so I can get the correct heights of divs and adjust the heights of others.

I've tried adjusting content heights here;

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
//Adjust stuff here
});
```

This doesn't work. When I use a breakpoint I can see that most of the page content has loaded but the text in one of the div's I want to resize isn't there. When should I be adjusting content heights

Comment: If the text isn't there, it's probably added with javascript, otherwise it would be there when the window has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: Its still too soon, the text hasn't appeared so as a result the heights are wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use **$(document).ready()** to wait until all DOM elements are loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Adjust stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run javascript after page is fully loaded. You can use the `onload` old style like.

```
window.onload = function(){
   // stuff
}
```

Its difference from `$(document).ready`. it wait until all image and css successful rendered. The `$(document).ready` is wait until `DOM` is ready.